# Simple copy paste function in JavaScript which supports Chrome and Mozilla as well

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I am making a simple Editor. So I want Simple Copy and Paste Function which can support Google Chrome Browser and Mozilla as well

Comment: This website does not offer a free coding service. You have to provide your attempts too and we help you where you are stuck. So.... what have you tried so far?

Comment: Define "Copy and Paste Function"...

Comment: You don't need to support IE at all?

Comment: What's wrong with the built in browser functionalities that do this already?

Answer (score 1):

You better sit down for this:

- Copying: **CTRL + C**
- Pasting: **CTRL + V**

Works great in most browsers, but not on Mac as they don't have the same CTRL key like PC users. Mac users have the CMD key for that.

For Mac users:

- Copying: **CMD + C**
- Pasting: **CMD + V**

Comment: "Thank you" sparky! My friend actually pointed this out just now. But it was half-serious answer on my behalf anyways. @bzlm Yes, even in IE6 :)

Comment: @Kalle:  Macs have a CTRL key... it's just not the key Mac OS uses for shortcuts like cut, copy & paste.